# webrequest.httprequest not returning any value

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, newrelic, system.net.httpwebrequest, newrelic-platform

```
var baseAddress = "https://insights-collector.newrelic.com/v1/accounts/111111/events";
var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(baseAddress));
http.Accept = "application/json";
http.ContentType = "application/json";
http.Method = "POST";
http.Headers.Add("X-Insert-Key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(jsondata);

**Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream();**

newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
newStream.Close();
var response = http.GetResponse();

var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
var sr = new StreamReader(stream);

content = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString();
```

when i execute the above code in my local machine i am getting response from newrelic website but when i move the same code to the windows server 2012, compiler is not going after this line

```
Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream();
```

and also it was not throwing any exception.

Comment: Have you try to set the  'Timeout' property of the HttpWebRequest for examle 10000 milliseconds/10 seconds.

Comment: I don't think timeout will resolve this becuase, Above code is working on my local machine but not working on server.

Comment: Yes it is not the solution but at least it can give the exception for further debugging.

Comment: tried that, but still no use.

Comment: Have you tried curl?  cat example_events.json | curl -d @- -X
  POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Insert-Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE"
  https://insights-collector.newrelic.com/v1/accounts/YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID/events

Comment: I set the time to 10 sec and it was returning the below exception System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context

Comment: So can you ping that site really from server?